# Telephone Conversation

Tags: telephone

When you call an acquaintance and she is struggling to recognize you what do native speakers say to make sure that she recognized him?

> Person A: Hey, this is Joseph from the math class.
>
> Person B: hmm[thinking...].
>
> Person A: [Trying to emphasize] Did you recognize me? Or Have you recalled me? What do you guys think is a good of way of asking this?

Comment: This is more "social mores"/invitation to discussion. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate all interrogation: Do you remember me?  Can you tell who I am? etc.  Instead, continue to give ideas:  I sit two seats down from you, I'm friends with Anna, I asked you for a pencil last week, etc.  If the person doesn't get it from a few tips, then you are asking too much of someone - they don't know you.  Apologize, and ask someone else.

Comment: Can we say: Do you recognize me? Or Did you remember/recognize me?

Comment: No, it's just annoying to be put on the spot like that.  If they do recognize you, it will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, Mom.**

I actually overheard this conversation once.

"Hi Mom it's me, Jack."

"......."

"Jack Smith"

;-)

*Name-Changed-to-Avoid-Public-Embarrassment

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to ask that question, then in standard English you might say:

> Do you remember me?
>   Do you know who this is?
>   Do you remember me from class?

In particular, it's "do you", not "did you" or "have you" since you are inquiring whether the person recalls you at that moment. "Recognize me" is also a little unusual since without modification "recognize" refers to visual appearance under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't normally ask, "Do you remember me?"  It's too aggressive.  They will show that they know you by their voice and attitude.

If they can't remember who you are, start by describing where you were when you met each other.  (E.g. "We met at a party on Wednesday." or "We go to the same art class.")  Then, if you need to, describe yourself in more detail.  ("I was wearing an orange hat."  "I'm the tall man who sits at the front.")

Here's an example of an informal conversation in British English:

> Anne: Hello?
>
> Bob: It's me!
>
> Anne: Er... I'm not sure I....
>
> Bob: It's Bob!  We met at the nightclub on Saturday.  I was the guy who helped you find your mobile phone.
>
> Anne: Oh!  Hi, Bob!

By the way, the *it* in *It's me!* and *It's Bob!* has no meaning.  Bob said "it" because every sentence in English needs a subject.